# automatic redeployment of aar file in JBoss AS on exception

Tags: jboss, apache-axis

I have web services deployed as AAR(Axis Archive) within JBoss AS 6.1.

I would like to know if it is possible for a java program in aar

to automatically redeploy itself on some critical exception.

I hope I may embed some codes to tell the container(JBoss AS) inside try ~ catch block to

redeploy my java web service in aar form without human intervention.

Anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to my idea.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/243356

This is the proposed solution that I have not yet done.